# binding a list of objects from Javascript to model in ASP.NET MVC2 Controller

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON that was obtained after calling JSON.stringify from my javascript

```
{"parameters":"[{\"ParamName\":\"@s\",\"ParamValue\":\"12\"},{\"ParamName\":\"@t\",\"ParamValue\":\"21\"}]"}
```

How do i map this to the following model in my ASP.Net MVC2 controller

```
public class SCVM
{
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<Parameters> parameters { get; set; }

    public SCVM()
    {
        parameters = new List<Parameters>();
    }
}

public class Parameters
{
    public string ParamName { get; set; }
    public string ParamValue { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get this in either a dictionary format or a list objects, but finding difficult to work it out the right way.

Comment: there is something wrong with your json. your parameters aren't stored as seperate objects but as a string. paste your javascript code aswell.

Comment: this is the content that i copied from the developer tool of chrome. The JS that i use is : `JSON.stringify(parametersCollection)', `var parametersCollection = [];` and this parametersCollection is an array of the following object `function QueryParameters(paramName, paramValue)
{
    this.ParamName = paramName;
    this.ParamValue = paramValue;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your json would look like this: it probably should. (see my comment on your question)

```
{
    "parameters":[
        {
            "ParamName":"@s",
            "ParamValue":"12"
        },
        {
            "ParamName":"@t",
            "ParamValue":"21"
        }
    ]
}
```

with this piece of javascript you'll create the correct json:

```
var parametersCollection = {
    parameters: []
}; 

function QueryParameters(paramName, paramValue) { this.ParamName = paramName;     this.ParamValue = paramValue; }

parametersCollection.parameters.push(new QueryParameters("@s", "12"));
parametersCollection.parameters.push(new QueryParameters("@t", "21"));

var json = JSON.stringify(parametersCollection);
```

you could deserialize is with Json.NET [see here](http://james.newtonking.com/) like so:

```
SCVM scvm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SCVM>(json);
```

where json is a string with the json formatted like I showed

[Here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) is an excellent tutorial on how to post json data to an MVC2 site using jquery. You wouldn't even have to use the Json.NET lib to deserialize your json.

Comment: My JSON is similar to what you have given. And, how do i get the `json` in the above line to the controller.

Comment: Also is there no built-in mechanism to get this data in the correct format to the controller (built-in model binding)?

Comment: The use of JSON.stringify alongwith the json2.js solved the problem.